# Does it support disk brakes?

Tags: brakes

I found these holes (as in the pictures) and wanted to know if it supports disk brakes or not.
I am upgrading the whole thing and calculating a budget.

Thank you in advance :)

[image: back]

[image: front]

Comment: From the looks of it it’s so old that disc brakes didn’t even exist yet.

Comment: Yeah.. It is! We are talking 20+ years old (may be more..)
I'm sending it to a local shop, he promised to upgrade it as much as possible xD
Thanks

Comment: Just don’t let them weld on disc brake mounts, the front fork is probably not strong enough. And be aware that the rear wheel dropouts are probably too narrow for modern freewheel hubs.

Comment: Ok, @Michael. You say it doesn't even support multiple speed cassette thing? or just the modern "freewheel hub" (You can see I am not really an expert )

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The shop said it will add the minimum number of speeds. You think it's a swindle? Don't really want body modifications.. :/

Comment: The frame is not sufficiently strong to withstand the force of the disk brakes on the fork and seat stay tubes.

Comment: In fact, I'd recommend against doing any upgrades to this bike at all. Buying the bike you want would give you way more value for your money, especially if you find a nice deal on a used one.

Comment: Got it. No disk breaks.. Minimal upgrades (cheap ones just to get it up and running)
I am kinda bored I need this thing to run, but I won't be buying a new one tho..

Thank you all <3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Those eyelets are for mounting mudguards or fenders.

Comment: Thanks a lot! saves me the hassle of buying expensive kits :)

Comment: Or a rear rack.